# Me.Requery appears to be doing no action on form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have searched and have found a lot of information on using requery on a subform, but I can't seem to find anything that indicates attempting to requery the active form with a new recordset.

I have a form based on a query.  I am using an unbound text box to capture the address which needs to be searched then changing the sql statement in the query to locate the records then attempting to use me.requery to load the new results.

The code is updating the sql statement, but the form is not requerying with the new record results.  My code is below.

I am fairly new to access and VBA, and appreciate any wisdom you may have.  Also, is there ANYTHING that I could be doing in other code which would cause this to fail?

---

```
Private Sub Command51_Click()

Dim d As DAO.Database
Dim q As DAO.QueryDef
Dim Addy As String
Dim Search As String


Set d = CurrentDb()
Set q = d.QueryDefs("SQL_Search")

If IsNull(Me!Addy) Then
    MsgBox ("Please select a valid address from the list and try again.")
    GoTo CleanUp
Else: End If

Addy = Me!Addy

Search = "select * from dbo_ECNumberVerify Where (((dbo_ECNumberVerify.invalidrecord)=False) AND ((dbo_ECNumberVerify.updated)=False) AND ((dbo_ECNumberVerify.Locations) Like '*" & Addy & "*'));"

'Send SQL SP execute command.
q.SQL = Search

Me.Requery

CleanUp:

Set q = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: It shows the updated string.  I can verify everything except the requery is working.  if i actually close and reload the form, the data reflects the query from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you have a query, but the query is never set or attached to the forms record source in "any way". So the “query” acts independent from the form data source.

You can simply stuff the sql directly into the forms reocrdsouce like this:

```
Me.RecordSource = Search
```

(so you don’t need all of your existing code, nor do you need the queryDef.

And when you set the forms SQL directly as per above, then a requery is done automatic for you. So the code required will look like this:

```
Dim strSearch     As String

If IsNull(Me.Addy) Then
   MsgBox ("Please select a valid address fromthe list and try again.")
   Exit Sub
End If

strSearch = "select * from dbo_ECNumberVerify WHERE " & _
            "(invalidrecord = False) AND (updated = False) AND " _
            "(Locations Like '*" & Addy & "*')"
Me.RecordSource = strSearch
```

So you don't need much code, and you really don't need to use + declare the querydef at all.

Comment: THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH!  This works beautifully.  Sometimes being a beginner (and almost always being self-taught) can suck.  I really appreciate your reply!

Comment: On a side note, did you see any reason that the requery wouldn't run from the original code?  I wish I could also understand why that didn't work.

Comment: @ChristaFoster like Albert was saying, the "query" with is requeried has nothing to do with the query associated with the `q` querydef unless you associated them with `Me.RecordSource = strSearch`

Comment: When you create a query in code, it runs 100% independent of the form. That code could even run without the form open. So when you write code and create a query, they are not by “magic” attached to some form. Writing such code thus allows you to do data processing and updating of data – say like some payroll calculations – such code thus is not aware or associated or attached to the forms reocrdset. You can create 10 such quires in code – and just because 10 forms exists that happen to be attached to the table, they are all independent objects.